# scripts.js file not found in console

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am totally newborn in jquery and almost in everything related to programming. Well I had to move my javascript to an independet sheet apart from html. I made a try first in my html to see if that was working, introducing an alert. But when I moved to the scripts.js it seems not to be working. This is how I have it linked:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"</script>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitterbootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

  <script src="js/jquery.stellar.min.js"></script>
  <script src=“js/scripts.js”></script>
```

Acording to my website console, scripts.js is not found, but I can not find why? Any hints?Thanks in advance!

Comment: what is with the fancy quoutes `“js/scripts.js”`

Answer (score 2):

```
<script src=“js/scripts.js”></script>
```

Replace it with below line , as you used the wrong quotes.

```
<script src='js/scripts.js'></script>
```

Comment: Copy and paste from URL get this trouble. Thank You Nikhil!

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
 <script src=“js/scripts.js”> </script>
```

to

```
<script src="js/scripts.js" />
```

Comment: Ey thank you!This kind of worked, but is weird since I literalluy copied the code from task in my online class and the quites were these "" not the other you asked me to use. What it seems not to be recognized is the    <script src='js/jquery.stellar.min.js'></script>  in console it reads like this:Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found). Any ideas? thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Ya it's annoying, but some time unicode system confuse between characters that are similar, in you case "  quotation mark changed with 
“   left double quotation mark. That's why we prefer utf - 8 code system.